# Google map api v3: find multiple paths using DistanceMatrixService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web

I am using Google map api for finding distance between two points with the help of DistanceMatrixService(). In the success callback of getDistanceMatrix(), I can get the distance between two points. There could be multiple paths between two points but I always get the length of shortest path. How could I get all path distances? Please refer the code below:

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [--some origins--],
    destinations: [--some destinations--],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
}, function (response, status) {
        for (var i = 0, length = response.rows[0].elements.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (response.rows[0].elements[i].status == 'NOT_FOUND') {
                alert('Source or destination address could not be found.');
                return;
            }

            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[i].distance.text;
            var duration = response.rows[0].elements[i].duration.text;
        }
});
```

In above code, the array `response.rows[0].elements` always turns out to have length one. It should have more that one objects if there are multiple paths between source and destination. How to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: [Suggested Routes Option in Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676386/suggested-routes-option-in-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) doesn't allow for multiple routes, it always calculates the shortest/best  distance.

If you need alternate routes and only have a single origin and destination, user the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), set `provideRouteAlternatives` to `true`.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests):

> provideRouteAlternatives (optional) when set to true specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.